# Way to highlight code in textarea with jquery?

Tags: jquery, syntax-highlighting, codehighlighter

Is there any good and logical ways to highlight code inside textarea via jQuery? If there is, please share.

Comment: do you mean anything wrapped in a `<code>` tag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there isn't. You can apply styles to the entire textarea, but not part of the text in it.

You would need something that works as a replacement for the textarea, [here](http://hotware.wordpress.com/2007/05/31/a-nice-collection-of-textarea-replacement-html-editors/) is a list of some.

Answer (score 22):

You could use CodeMirror http://codemirror.net/

> ...a versatile text editor implemented in JavaScript for the browser. It is specialized for editing code, and comes with a number of [language modes](http://codemirror.net/mode/index.html) and [addons](http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#addons) that implement more advanced editing functionality.
>
> A rich [programming API](http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#api) and a CSS [theming](http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#styling) system are available for customizing CodeMirror to fit your application, and extending it with new functionality...

Comment: I know this is really late but I dont get HOW to use codemirror

Answer (score 1):

If by code, you mean SQL, PHP etc., take a look at [Codepress](http://codepress.sourceforge.net/changelog.php). It's a real-time, syntax highlighting editor, written in Javascript.

**Edit:**

If you'd prefer a more modern and actively-maintained alternative, you should look at [Ace](https://ace.c9.io/#nav=about).

Answer (score 1):

You can highlight a part of a text with the follow search code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("textarea").highlightTextarea({
              words: ["first word","an other word"]
        });
    });
</script>
```

Find more about highlighting in a textarea on [Highlight text into a textarea](http://www.strangeplanet.fr/work/jquery-highlighttextarea/)

Answer (score 0):

i was looking too for a live syntax coloring best solution so i found a working , ancient software(2007) that is older than textarea(witch is working too) :

***1.Codepress***

https://sourceforge.net/projects/codepress/files/

then in index.html the line 117 replaced with

```
<textarea spellcheck="false" id="codepress2" class="codepress javascript linenumbers-off" style="width:700px;height:200px;" wrap="off">
```

will had live syntax coloring like notepad++ / editplus in web meaning
small code could be "repainted" , "reforget" to this age ...

it's up to you ...

***2.MIT    LDT***  =minimalist syntax coloring
https://github.com/kueblc/LDT

..all tests i did are in a custom **apache php 8.1 mariadb custom server** (**remote buggy/spies free**) so these two works fine!

so the answer is : **in case you open to recoding something** these can be recoded in jquery with the author accept (check the licenses for more info)