# Is it possible to have syntax highlighting for HTML/CSS/JS in <textarea>?

Tags: javascript, html, css, syntax-highlighting, codemirror

Here's a pen of what I mean:

http://codepen.io/archiehicklin/pen/oZQdEG

```html
 <textarea id="html" placeholder="HTML"></textarea>
    <textarea id="css" placeholder="CSS"></textarea>
    <textarea id="js" placeholder="JS"></textarea>
<iframe id="code"></iframe>
```

Trying to build a small offline wysiwyg editor and was wondering if it's possible to have some form of real-time syntax highlighting for the code input into textarea - similar to codepen or jsfiddle.

I've come across the Codemirror library but it doesn't seem like it would work for live input.

Comment: you have the 2021's answer here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/69984857/5781320

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot directly control syntax highlighting in a textarea. You can try JS libraries like http://www.cdolivet.com/editarea/ or if you just wnat to do it all by yourself, you can go for **contenteditable** .

Contenteditable is an html Attribute that enables textarea like editing in any element like `div` , `span` etc.

Although you will have to use a lot of javascript to interpret the language and highlight it accordingly.

```html
<div contenteditable="true" style="width:100%;height:200px;border:1px solid #000">
<b>This is bold text</b><br/>
<u>This is underlined text</u><br/>
and so on..<br/>
<font color="#f00">class</font> <font color="#0f0">Sample</font><br/>
<em>{</em><br/>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

If planning some third party libraries you can go for highlight.js:
https://highlightjs.org/

It can be integrated with your contenteditable.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.10.0/highlight.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.10.0/languages/php.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.10.0/styles/purebasic.min.css" />
<script>hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();</script>
<pre><code class="html">class test {}</code></pre>
```